# Import variable in Process::Start

Tags: c++, visual-c++, process.start, working-directory

I use `Process::Start` function to run an .exe from another program.

I 'm thinking storing the .exe in location where main program (vc++) is stored. That way I could via `GetCurrentDir` get always the location of .exe too and then import location in `Process::Start`, as a variable. Is this possible?

GetCurrentDir:

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* defines FILENAME_MAX */
#ifdef WINDOWS
    #include <direct.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir _getcwd
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir getcwd
 #endif

 char cCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];

 if (!GetCurrentDir(cCurrentPath, sizeof(cCurrentPath)))
     {
     return errno;
     }
```

Location is stored in cCurrentPath variable. I tried with:

```
Process::Start("%s\\application.exe", cCurrentPath);
```

but didn't work out. How can I fix this?

Comment: The current directory is unrelated to the directory where the EXE is located (observe the existence of `chdir` - do you really believe it physically moves the executable when changing the current directory?). It may be the same by coincidence, but it doesn't have to be. The correct way to discover the location of your EXE is with `GetModuleFileName(NULL)`

Comment: `Process::Start` doesn't do string formatting. Build the string first, with `String::Format` or `CString::Format` or good old `sprintf` or `strcat`, then pass the resulting string to `Process::Start`.

Comment: Thank's for your replies. I used `GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, path, 1000);`instead, in order to get path in char. I formatted string using `sprintf(mypath, "%s\\application.exe", path);`. I used `Process::Start("%s", mypath);` to run the .exe, but fails. What I am missing.

Comment: `GetModuleFileName` gives you the full path to your EXE file, including its file name - not just the directory.

Comment: My aim is to run a second .exe (it's another program that is located by me in the same directory that my main progam is located). Main program calls .exe to run. `Process::Start` must contain the path of the main program -including the name of the second .exe- in order to run second .exe too. Since `GetModuleFileName` reurns the name of the main program, can I fix this returning only it's location?

Comment: You strip the file name from the string, leaving only the directory. You could do that with `PathCchRemoveFileSpec`, for example. Then you append the other file name.